# MS Access 2010 Resolving Invalid Argument Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm using a very simple query to update a field in SharePoint.  The field is a choice field and the table I'm updating indicates the exact value of one of the choices.

Both SharePoint and my internal table indicate the field (Folders) is a text format.  I've ran this query many times but suddenly started to receive an error:

> Invalid Argument

I've searched online and tried everything to no avail.  The database is well under the limit.

**The SQL:**

```
UPDATE tbltest INNER JOIN [Title Clearing] ON (tbltest.[Number] =
[Title Clearing].[Number]) AND (tbltest.Client = [Title 
Clearing].Client)   SET [Title Clearing].Folders = [tbltest]![Folders];
```

Comment: How are you running the query? With VBA? Also, MS Access tables are different from SharePoint lists. Please specify objects used and the whole code and finally please edit by breaking code line to avoid horizontal scrolling in post.

Comment: I'm manaully running the query, not in vba... Right click/Open.  That is the entire code, [Title Clearing] is referring to the linked SharePoint table.  I'm just trying to change the multiple choice field with a group of numbers in the tbltest table.

Comment: Perhaps you mean [tbltest]`.`[Folders] instead of [tbltest]`!`[Folders] in the line reading `SET [Title Clearing].Folders = [tbltest]![Folders];`